# why is my customized LinkedList not working?

Tags: java, data-structures, collections, linked-list, nodes

I am trying to create customized LinkedList to understand the data structure better. I couldn't figure out what is the issue of my LinkedList class.

```
package numberlist.primitivelist.objectlist;

public class ObjectLinkedList extends ObjectList implements Copiable {

Node firstNode;

/**
 * ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 *
 * Method: ObjectLinkedList() description:constructor
 *
 * @author Jinyu Wu Date: 2017/2/4
 * ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 */
public ObjectLinkedList() {
    firstNode = null;
}

/**
 * ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 *
 * Method: add() description: Insert an item into the list
 *
 * @param index position of the list
 * @param obj the element is going to be inserted
 * @author Jinyu Wu Date: 2017/2/4
 * ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 */
@Override
public void add(int index, Object obj) {
    Node tempNode = firstNode;
    Node currentNode = new Node(obj);
    if (index == 0) {
        firstNode = currentNode;
        return;
    }
    if (index < 0 || index > size()) {
        System.out.println("add(ObjectLinkedList) index out of bound exception");
    } else {
        for (int i = 1; i <= index; i++) {
            tempNode = tempNode.getNext();
            if (i == index - 1) {
                if (index != size() - 1) {
                    currentNode.setNext(tempNode.getNext());
                } else {
                    currentNode.setNext(null);
                }
                tempNode.setNext(currentNode);
            }
        }
    }

}

/**
 * ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 *
 * Method: removeAt() description: remove an item from a position of the
 * list
 *
 * @param index position in the list
 * @author Jinyu Wu Date: 2017/2/4
 * ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 */
@Override
public void removeAt(int index) {
    if (index < 0 || index > size()) {
        System.out.println("removeAt(ObjectLinkedList) index out of bound exception");
    } else {
        Node tempNode = firstNode;
        if (index == 0) {
            firstNode = firstNode.getNext();
        } else {
            for (int i = 1; i <= index; i++) {
                tempNode = tempNode.getNext();
                if (i == index - 1) {
                    if (index != size() - 1) {
                        tempNode.setNext(tempNode.getNext().getNext());
                    } else {
                        tempNode.setNext(null);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}

/**
 * ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 *
 * Method: remove() description: remove a specific item from a position of
 * the list
 *
 * @param obj target object is going to be removed
 * @author Jinyu Wu Date: 2017/2/4
 * ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 */
@Override
public void remove(Object obj) {
    if (size() > 0) {
        Node tempNode = firstNode;
        for (int i = 0; i <= size(); i++) {
            if (tempNode.equals(obj)) {
                tempNode.setNext(tempNode.getNext().getNext());
                break;
            }
            if (i < size() - 1) {
                tempNode = tempNode.getNext();
            }
        }

        System.out.println("target object is not found inside the linkedList(remove)");
    }
}

/**
 * ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 *
 * Method: get() description:get an item from the list
 *
 * @param index position in the list
 * @author Jinyu Wu Date: 2017/2/4
 * @return double ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 */
@Override
public Object get(int index) {
    if (index < 0 || index > size()) {
        System.out.println("get(ObjectLinkedList) index out of bound exception");
        return null;
    } else if (index == 0) {
        return firstNode;
    } else {
        Node tempNode = firstNode;
        for (int i = 0; i <= index; i++) {
            if (i == index - 1) {
                tempNode = tempNode.getNext();
                return tempNode;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("objectLinkedList get method nothing found");
        return null;
    }

}

/**
 * ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 *
 * Method: toString() description: print out the content of the list
 *
 * @author Jinyu Wu Date: 2017/2/4
 * @return Integer ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 */
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "ObjectLinkedList{" + "firstNode=" + firstNode + '}';
}

/**
 * ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 *
 * Method: find() description:get an item from the list
 *
 * @author Jinyu Wu Date: 2017/2/4
 * @param obj Object is going to be found
 * @return Integer ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 */
@Override
public int find(Object obj) {
    Node tempNode = firstNode;
    Node newNode = new Node(obj);
    if (newNode.equals(firstNode)) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        for (int i = 1; i < size(); i++) {
            if (tempNode.equals(newNode)) {
                return i;
            }
            tempNode = tempNode.getNext();
        }
        return -1;
    }

}

/**
 * ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 *
 * Method: size() description:get the size of the list
 *
 * @author Jinyu Wu Date: 2017/2/4
 * @return Integer ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 */
@Override
public int size() {
    int size = 1;
    if (firstNode == null) {
        return 0;
    }
    try {
        for (Node n = firstNode; n.getNext() != null; n = n.getNext()) {
            size++;
        }
        return size;
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        return size;
    }
}

/**
 * ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 *
 * Method: deepCopy() description: make a deepCoy for this object
 *
 * @author Jinyu Wu Date: 2017/2/4
 * @return String ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 */
@Override
public ObjectLinkedList deepCopy() {
    ObjectLinkedList newList = new ObjectLinkedList();
    Node currentNode = firstNode;

    for (int i = 0; i < size(); i++) {
        Node newNode = new Node(currentNode.getValue());
        newList.add(i, newNode);
        currentNode = currentNode.getNext();
    }

    return newList;

}
```

}

Here is what do test it by using Junit test

```
package numberlist.primitivelist.objectlist;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;


public class ObjectLinkedListTest {

ObjectLinkedList list;
Money m1, m2;
Node node1, node2;

public ObjectLinkedListTest() {

}

@Before
public void setUp() {
    list = new ObjectLinkedList();
    m1 = new Money(5, (byte) 6);
    node1 = new Node(m1);
    list.add(0, node1);

    m2 = new Money(2, (byte) 4);
    node2 = new Node(m2);
    list.add(1, node2);
}

/**
 * Test of add method, of class ObjectLinkedList.
 */
@Test
public void testAdd() {
    assertEquals(list.get(0), node1);
}

/**
 * Test of removeAt method, of class ObjectLinkedList.
 */
@Test
public void testRemoveAt() {
    list.removeAt(1);
    assertNull(list.get(1));
}

/**
 * Test of remove method, of class ObjectLinkedList.
 */
@Test
public void testRemove() {
    list.remove(m2);
    assertNull(list.get(1));
}

/**
 * Test of get method, of class ObjectLinkedList.
 */
@Test
public void testGet() {
}

/**
 * Test of toString method, of class ObjectLinkedList.
 */
@Test
public void testToString() {
}

/**
 * Test of find method, of class ObjectLinkedList.
 */
@Test
public void testFind() {
    assertEquals(list.find(m1), 0);
    assertEquals(list.find(m2), 1);
}

/**
 * Test of size method, of class ObjectLinkedList.
 */
@Test
public void testSize() {
    assertEquals(list.size(), 2);
}

/**
 * Test of deepCopy method, of class ObjectLinkedList.
 */
@Test
public void testDeepCopy() {

}
```

}

Here is the error I got:

[Error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vmqhn.png)

My Node class:

```
package numberlist.primitivelist.objectlist;

public class Node {

private Node nextNode;
private Object obj;

/**
 * ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 *
 * Method: Node() description: constructor
 *
 * @author Jinyu Wu Date: 2017/2/4
 * @param obj set the value
 */
public Node(Object obj) {
    this.obj = obj;
    this.nextNode = null;
}

/**
 * ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 *
 * Method: getValue() description: get the value of object
 *
 * @author Jinyu Wu Date: 2017/2/4
 * @return return the object
 */
public Object getValue() {
    return this.obj;
}

/**
 * ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 *
 * Method: setValue() description: setValue for the Node
 *
 * @author Jinyu Wu Date: 2017/2/4
 * @param obj return the value
 */
public void setValue(Object obj) {
    this.obj = obj;
}

/**
 * ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 *
 * Method: getValue() description: get the next value of the currentNode
 *
 * @author Jinyu Wu Date: 2017/2/4
 * @return return next node
 */
public Node getNext() {
    if (nextNode != null) {
        return this.nextNode;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

/**
 * ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 *
 * Method: setNext() description: set next value for the Node
 *
 * @author Jinyu Wu Date: 2017/2/4
 * @param node set next node
 */
public void setNext(Node node) {
    this.nextNode = node;
}

}
```

Comment: How is class `Node` defined?

Comment: Also, how have you tried to debug the code? What are your findings, can you provide a smaller piece of code which still behaves strangely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that this is for practice or an assignment, java has a generic implementation of `LinkedList` already [see the api docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html).

You may find one of the many [texts](https://www.google.co.nz/search?tbm=bks&hl=en&q=Data+Structures+and+Algorithms+in+Java%2C+6th+Edition) on data structures in java helpul, though usually their implementations use generics rather than `Object`,

---

For your specific problem you notice that in your testAdd method you call

```
assertEquals(list.get(0), m1);
```

This is comparing a `Node` to a `Money` object which will always fail.

<strike>You could `assertEquals(list.get(0).getValue(), m1);`</strike> This wont work unless you alter the `get()` method to return a `Node` rather than an `Object` as it is currently doing.

You are having similar issues with the other tests, where `list.get()` returns a `Node`, not the data within that node.

Alternatively edit the `get()` method to return the data in the node:

```
    ...
    } else if (index == 0) {
        return firstNode.getValue();
    } else {
    // etc, you have multiple returns in this method
```

**Edit**

Your `testRemoveAt()` will throw an `NullPointerException` as the get method tries to call `tempNode.getNext().getValue()`, but you have only one Money object in the list after the test removes the second object so `getNext()` returns null.

**Edit 2**

It may be most useful for you to become more familiar with your debugger. Maybe try a video tutorial for [netbeans](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=joWldbcp1So). Then you *investigate your exceptions*. For example, running your first test gives:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected :Node@4f2410ac
Actual   :Money@722c41f4
```

This means that the testAdd() test failed on its call to `assertEquals(list.get(0), m1);`

Something to note here is that the signature for `assertEquals` takes its *expected* value first, and the *actual* value second. So change that line to `assertEquals(m1, list.get(0));` and re-run the test.

Now the output is:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected :Money@722c41f4
Actual   :Node@4f2410ac
```

So the test expectod a `Money` object (thats the `m1` parameter) but `list.get(0)` returned a `Node` object instead.

Either the test is expecting the wrong thing or the `get()` method is returning the wrong thing. I'm going to assume that when you call `list.get(0)` you actually want to get a `Money` object back, so that means the test is **right** and we need to look at the implementation of `list.get()`.

You have:

```
1.  public Object get(int index) {
2.      if (index < 0 || index > size()) {
3.          System.out.println("get(ObjectLinkedList) index out of bound exception");
4.          return null;
5.      } else if (index == 0) {
6.          return firstNode;
7.      } else {
8.          Node tempNode = firstNode;
9.          for (int i = 0; i <= index; i++) {
10.             if (i == index - 1) {
11.                 tempNode = tempNode.getNext();
12.                 return tempNode;
13.             }
14.         }
15.         System.out.println("objectLinkedList get method nothing found");
16.         return null;
17.      }
18.  }
```

And on line 6 and 12 you can see the problem: the function is returning a `Node` when we actually want `Money`; or more specifically, the value of the `Node` as an object. So the following changes can be made those lines

```
6.     return firstNode.getValue();
```

and

```
12.    return tempNode.getValue();
```

and then running the `testAdd` again it should pass.

This will probably **not** fix all the bugs that are in the code, but it gives you an idea of the steps to follow to find the problem.

Your code is well formatted, you have made the effort to put javadoc on your functions and you're persistent. Nice work, keep at it.

Comment: Hi there, I took your advice, but now i got theses error. I updated my question could you please take a took again? Thanks

Comment: @JINYUWU Sure what IDE are you using?

Comment: I am using NetBean

Comment: Thanks, I follow what you did and it passes. but is there any error with my removeAt and remove method? because I kept getting NPE

Comment: Hi @JINYUWU. I mentioned that may occur in my first edit earlier. It is because the code tries to call `getValue()` on a  `null` Node. Debugging is a really valuable skill that can be best learned by practice and I suggest that you work through the other bugs.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the `size()` method, you didn't take into consideration two edge cases:

1. When the list is empty (you'll get NPE for trying to execute `n.getNext()`
2. When there's only one Node in the list (it doesn't have "next" so it'll return zero instead of 1)

You can easily fix it by adding the following in the beginning of the method:

```
public int size() {
        int size = 1;
        if (firstNode == null) {
            return 0;
        }
        try {...
```

There is another bug in the method `add`. The for-loop is unnecessarily complicated and doesn't handle some edge cases. Modify it to:

```
public void add(int index, Object obj) {
    Node tempNode = firstNode;
    Node currentNode = new Node(obj);
    if (index < 0 || index > size()) {
        System.out.println("add(ObjectLinkedList) index out of bound exception: " + index + "; size: " + size());
    } else if (index == 0) {
        firstNode = currentNode;
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < index-1; i++) {
            tempNode = tempNode.getNext();
        }
        tempNode.setNext(currentNode);
    }
}
```

And the code will work.

Further, I would also "upgrade" `toString` method to something like:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    Node tmp = firstNode;
    String res = "" + firstNode;
    while (tmp.getNext() != null) {
        tmp = tmp.getNext();
        res += "," + tmp;
    }
    return "ObjectLinkedList{" + res + "}";
}
```

This way, when you print the list you'll be able to see all the elements, not only the first one.

Comment: after adding the code I got 1 though. It should be 2

Comment: That's because you have another bug in `add`. See updated answer.

Comment: I modified my code l like you did, but I still got the error. and now, there is a problem with my add, find, removeAt, and remove methods. I think the problem is my size() method. but I couldn't find the error

Comment: @JINYUWU what is the problem ? try to provide more details otherwise it's difficult to help you.